# Why are some functions called 'forms'?

Tags: terminology, differential-forms, quadratic-forms, modular-forms, bilinear-form

The question is simple: why are some functions called 'forms'? Modular 'forms', bilinear 'forms', differential 'forms', quadratic 'forms', and so forth. It is not concretely a mathematical question but I suppose the origin of the term must be mathematical, so I ask it here.

Thanks for the comment, it seems the question was already answered here:
[What do mathematicians mean when they say "form"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1865108/what-do-mathematicians-mean-when-they-say-form)

and here's another page: [Earliest use of the word "form" in mathematics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1943979/earliest-use-of-the-word-form-in-mathematics?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: maybe duplicated to (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1865108/what-do-mathematicians-mean-when-they-say-form)

Comment: That link covers the forms you listed that are not "modular" decently well.  Maybe modular is the only one left to ask about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See links: [What do mathematicians mean when they say "form"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1865108/what-do-mathematicians-mean-when-they-say-form?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I like this one: [Earliest use of the word "form" in mathematics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1943979/earliest-use-of-the-word-form-in-mathematics?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Link to wiki of Plato's theory of forms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_forms